# How to return all records from table A , if any one of the column has a specific value in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the sample data

If I pass lot name as a parameter, I want to return employees who has greater than 0 records in The specific Lot . Not just the one record but all the records of that employee.

Table A

```
Empid lotname itemcount
1     A       1
1     B       1
2     B       0
3     B       1
3     C       0
```

Parameter - B
Result :

```
Empid lotname itemcount
1     A       1
1     B       1
3     B       1
3     C       0
```

Because employee 3 and 1 has count in B lot. All the employee lot details should be returned.

Comment: Welcome, what have you tried so far, why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select data.* from A data,
(select  Empid,count(lotname)
 from A 
group by Empid
having count(lotname)>1) MulLotEmp
where data.lotname='B'
 and data.Empid=MulLotEmp.Empid;
```

Check if this query solves your problem. In this I created a inner table first for your first requirement that emp with multiple lot, then I mapped this table with actual table with condition of input lot name.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want all "1" and then only "0" if there is no "1".

One method is:

```
select a.*
from a
where itemcount = 1 or
      not exists (select 1 from a a2 where a2.empid = a.empid and a2.itemcount = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can use the `MAX` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT Empid,
       lotname,
       itemcount
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         MAX( itemcount ) OVER ( PARTITION BY Empid ) AS max_itemcount
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  max_itemcount = 1;
```

So, for you sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Empid, lotname, itemcount ) AS
SELECT 1, 'A', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'B', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'B', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'B', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'C', 0 FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> EMPID | LOTNAME | ITEMCOUNT
> ----: | :------ | --------:
>     1 | A       |         1
>     1 | B       |         1
>     3 | B       |         1
>     3 | C       |         0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ce53d2313d2fb922c16ddd141c9ef041)*

Answer (score 0):

The analytic function

```
sum(case when LOTNAME = 'B' /* parameter */ then ITEMCOUNT end) over (partition by EMPID) as lot_itemcnt
```

calculates for each customer the total number of items with the selected lot.

Feel free to use it as a bind variable, e.g.

```
sum(case when LOTNAME = ? /* parameter */ then ITEMCOUNT end) over (partition by EMPID) as lot_itemcnt
```

The whole query is than as follows

```
with cust as (
select 
  EMPID, LOTNAME, ITEMCOUNT,
  sum(case when LOTNAME = 'B' /* parameter */ then ITEMCOUNT end) over (partition by EMPID) as lot_itemcnt
from tab)
select 
  EMPID, LOTNAME, ITEMCOUNT
from cust
where lot_itemcnt >= 1;
```